# Proper syntax for Laravel 5.1 Artisan Command

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to make an artisan command for Laravel 5.1 and I'm getting stuck getting even the most basic version to work.

**Steps taken**

1) `php artisan make:console Zelda --command=zelda`

2) file created in `app/Console/Command/Zelda.php` with the following contents

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Zelda extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'zelda';
    protected $description = 'Command description.';
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle() {}
}
```

3) The autoloader in composer.json looks like this

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Console/Commands"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
"autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
},
```

4) then I run `php artisan list` and no zelda

What am I missing here?

Comment: Also...I did a composer autoload dump --optimize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there!  You've done everything you need to do to **create** your command class.  However, you still need to tell your application that it should **use** this command class.

That is, in your CLI application kernel file (as opposed to your web application's kernel) file you should see the following

```
#File: app/Console/Kernel.php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    //...    
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];
    //...
}
```

Once you've created you command (either manually or via `make:console`, you still need add your new command class (the full PHP class name) to the `$commands` array of the kernel file.

This

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    '\App\Console\Commands\Zelda',
];
```

or this

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\Zelda::class,
];
```

should get you where you need to be (I'm uncertain why Laravel 5.1's core code uses the magic constant `class` here)